# Minimum wavelength in black body radiation

Tags: thermal-radiation, wavelength, blackbody

Is there a minimum wavelength in a black body's radiation? If yes, is there a formula to calculate it?

In this [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black_body.svg) from Wikipedia, it does seem that the curve is touching the x-axis rather than being an asymptote, so I feel there should be a minimum wavelength.

Comment: You can just take [Planck's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) and find out where it is zero yourself. (Spoiler: Only at zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a minimum wavelength in a black body's radiation?

No... Or rather: Yes, Zero.

> In this image from Wikipedia, it does seem that the curve is touching
>   the x-axis rather than being an asymptote

It's not. The curve approaches zero rather quickly. So, it's hard to illustrate.